# Get count of array value is Powerwall

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

Following is the array and I want count of if `product` `name` is Powerwall

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user] => 58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2
                [company] => tesla
                [product] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Powerwall
                        [category] => product
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [user] => 58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2
                [company] => tesla
                [product] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Powerwall
                        [category] => product
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [user] => 58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2
                [company] => tesla
                [product] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Powerwall
                        [category] => product
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [user] => 58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2
                [company] => tesla
                [product] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Powerwall
                        [category] => product
                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [user] => 58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2
                [company] => tesla
                [product] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Powerwall
                        [category] => product
                    )

            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [user] => 58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2
                [company] => tesla
                [product] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Powerwall
                        [category] => product
                    )

            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [user] => 58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2
                [company] => tesla
                [product] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Powerwall
                        [category] => product
                    )

            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [user] => 58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2
                [company] => tesla
                [product] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Powerwall
                        [category] => product
                    )

            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [user] => 58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2
                [company] => tesla
                [product] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Model S
                        [category] => product
                    )

            )

    )
```

Output needed `8 for Powerwall and 1 for Model S`

Comment: You mean you want to count the no. of times Powerwall product name appears?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: yes @ObjectManipulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your array and increment the counter `$count` every time **Powerwall** is found.

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if ($arr['product']['name'] == 'Powerwall') {
        $count++;
    }
}
echo "Powerwall count = " . $count;
```

Comment: Its working @Object Manipulator, Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `array_column` and `array_count_values` for counting the no

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/778198)

```
  <?php
 $dataarray=Array
    (
        0 => Array
            (
                "user" => "58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2",
                "company" => "tesla",
                "product" => Array
                    (
                        "name" => "Powerwall",
                        "category" => "product",
                    )

            ),

        1 => Array
            (
                "user" => "58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2",
                "company" => "tesla",
                "product" => array
                    (
                        "name" => "Powerwall",
                        "category" => "product",
                    )

            ),

        2 => array
            (
                "user" => "58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2",
                "company" => "tesla",
                "product" => array
                    (
                        "name" => "Powerwall",
                        "category" => "product",
                    )

            ),

        3 => array
            (
                "user" => "58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2",
                "company" => "tesla",
                "product" => array
                    (
                        "name" => "Powerwall",
                        "category" => "product",
                    )

            ),

        4 => array
            (
                "user" => "58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2",
                "company" => "tesla",
                "product" => array
                    (
                        "name" => "Powerwall",
                        "category" => "product",
                    )

            ),

        5 => array
            (
                "user" => "58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2",
                "company" => "tesla",
                "product" => array
                    (
                        "name" => "Powerwall",
                        "category" => "product",
                    )

            ),

        6 => array
            (
                "user" => "58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2",
                "company" => "tesla",
                "product" => array
                    (
                        "name" => "Powerwall",
                        "category" => "product",
                    )

            ),

        7 => array
            (
                "user" => "58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2",
                "company" => "tesla",
                "product" => array
                    (
                        "name" => "Powerwall",
                        "category" => "product",
                    )

            ),

        8 => array
            (
                "user" => "58cb6fb8bf3c3600043ec1f2",
                "company" => "tesla",
                "product" => array
                    (
                        "name" => "Model S",
                        "category" => "product",
                    )

            ),

    );
$result= array_count_values(array_column(array_column($dataarray,"product"),"name"));
echo "Count: ".$result["Powerwall"];
```

Comment: This is working in fiddle but not in my code I'm getting this error array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values

Comment: can you copy paste my code and check might be you are missing something

Comment: I'd copied your code more than three times but still I'm getting error by the way thanks brother for the help.